# First Cohomology group trivial for a simply connected manifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

We know that the for a simply connected manifold X, both the first fundamental group and the first homology group are both trivial. Is it also true that the first cohomology group is also trivial?

I feel like its not, but for the solution im trying to derive I kind of want it to be true. Anyone able to clarify?

Comment: Have you tried using the universal [coefficient theorem for cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology)?

Comment: The first cohomology group is, intuitively, even more likely to be trivial than the first homology group. If the fundamental group is finite and abelian, the first cohomology group is trivial, while the first homology group is not (unless the fundamental group is itself trivial).

Comment: Hint: $H^1(X;\mathbb Z)\cong Hom(\pi_1(X),\mathbb Z)$